# how change color in datagrid view base on string

Tags: text, datagridview, colors

[enter image description here][1][**enter image description here**][2]

how to change specific genre text color with color in datagridview base on text

how to change specific genre text color with color in datagridview base on textcom/K8l1o.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgmkW.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a color from a name like this :

```
Color red = Color.FromName("Red");
```

If Color.FromName cannot find a match, it returns new Color(0,0,0);

Than you can use it in a paint event.

I noticed from your image you are using devexpress gridview, so you can try this code (untested !)

```
    private void gridView1_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gridView = sender as GridView;
        if (e.RowHandle >= 0)
        {
            if (gridView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridView.Columns["color"]) != null)
            {
                Color color = Color.FromName(gridView.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gridView.Columns["color"]).ToString());
                e.Appearance.BackColor = color;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: i copy paster raw, well there's no error but whre do i assign the color..?
i tweak a bit at last code like e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.red still make no red color..
but how do i use ur code?

Comment: you go to the gridview in designtime and doubleclick on the RowStyle event and there you just copy my code and thats it

Answer (score 0):

but i do it like this
  private void gridView1_RowCellStyle_1(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView View = sender as GridView;
            if (e.Column.FieldName == "genre")
            {
                string category = View.GetRowCellDisplayText(e.RowHandle, View.Columns["genre"]);
                if (category == "Gymnastics")
                {
                    e.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Magenta;
                }